# How to duplicate the values that were not randomly sampled from an array?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have an array of 9 elements.
I sample 4 elements randomly and repeat each one 3 times.

But I also want to repeat twice (in other array) the numbers that were not sampled.

For example:

yeses = [0,0,0,4,4,4,1,1,1,8,8,8]

I need:

noes = [1,1,2,2,3,3,5,5,6,6,7,7,9,9]

How can I do that?

```
allStims = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]

##Pick randomly 4 numbers and repeat each 3 times
yeses = np.repeat(random.sample(allStims, 4),3)
print(yeses)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a list comprehension to get all the values in the original list that aren't in `yeses`.

```
nos = np.repeat([x for x in allStims if x not in yeses], 2)
```

Comment: Is there a way to put both arrays in just 1 without using "concat': concat = np.concatenate((yeses, nos))

Comment: @Aizzaac That's probably the best way to do it, since the type is `numpy.ndarray`. The other option is to convert them to plain python lists first.